# I need help to sort out my incorrect query that doesn't display the text box date in php

Tags: php, html

I have created the text box as well as the query for database.But in my case I want to fetch the data from input field and store it in database.

What actually happens is when I use the function `$_POST['launch_date']` it displays the date that I add in db but when I store this in a variable and convert it to y-m-d format it doesn't give me the answer from the text field like `$launch_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['launch_date']));`.

when i print the both the above mentioned code in single line like `echo $_POST['launch_date'] .$launch_date."<br>";` I get the following results

> 30/01/2020 1970-01-01.

The first one is from my text box and the second one is from the variable that I have created.

Comment: PHP doesn't understand the date `30/01/2020`. It expects it to be mm/dd/yyyy, not dd/mm/yyyy. Use `date_create_from_format()` to tell it how to parse the date.

Comment: could you please make the query for that

Comment: You said `$_POST` return date that stored in db and in next line you said ` I store this in a variable and convert it to y-m-d format`. But PHP Only Accepts the Y-m-d Format so problem is while you are inserting date.

Comment: if you want string date in correct date then use
`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['launch_date']);
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime::create_from_format()` to specify the format of your dates.

```
$launch_date = DateTime::create_from_format('m/d/Y', $_POST['launch_date'])->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['launch_date'] = '30/01/2020';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['launch_date']);
$launch_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
echo $_POST['launch_date'] ." ".$launch_date."<br>";
```

Output: `30/01/2020 2020-01-30`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the / has confused the  format of m/d/Y (instead of d/m/Y). And if the date time is not valid (for instance, the month is greater that 12) is  in the American format, you'll get the default time (aka UNIX timestamp 0) ie 1970-1-1.

You can create date from user input by

```
$launch_date = DateTime::create_from_format('d/m/Y', $_POST['launch_date'])->format('Y-m-d');
```

This is create a date variable of the form Year-Month-Date.

You can change the format as per your requirement.

Y-m-d is the standard date format for MySql.

If You are using **PHP version 5.2 or lower you** , you will have to parse the date in to 'd'. 'm' and 'y' . Then you will have to create a new date.